# Не работает код из методички

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Скопировал код из методички по C++. Компилятор выдает 91 ошибку. Где я мог допустить ошибку?

**Tovar.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Tovar
{
    //атрибуты
    string naimenovanie;
    int kolichestvo;
    double stoimost;
public:
    Tovar();//конструктор без параметров
    Tovar(string, int, double);//конструктор с параметрами
    Tovar(const Tovar&);//конструктор копирования
    ~Tovar();//деструктор
    string get_naimenovanie();//селектор
    void set_naimenovanie(string);//модификатор
    int get_kolichestvo();//селектор
    void set_kolichestvo(int); //модификатор
    double get_stoimost();//селектор
    void set_stoimost(double); //модификатор
    void show();//просмотр атрибутов
};
```

**Tovar.cpp**

```
#include "Tovar.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
//конструктор без параметров
Tovar::Tovar()
{
    naimenovanie = "";
    kolichestvo = 0;
    stoimost = 0;
    cout << "Constructor bez parametrov dlia objecta" << this << endl;
}
//конструктор с параметрами
Tovar::Tovar(string N, int K, double S)
{
    naimenovanie = N;
    kolichestvo = K;
    stoimost = S;
    cout << "Constructor s parametrami dlia objecta" << this << endl;
}
//конструктор копирования
Tovar::Tovar(const Tovar &t)
{
    naimenovanie = t.naimenovanie;
    kolichestvo = t.kolichestvo;
    stoimost = t.stoimost;
    cout << "Constructor copirovania dlia objecta" << this << endl;
}
//деструктор
Tovar::~Tovar()
{
    cout << "Destructor dlia objecta" << this << endl;
}
//селекторы
string Tovar::get_naimenovanie()
{
    return naimenovanie;
}
int Tovar::get_kolichestvo()
{
    return kolichestvo;
}
double Tovar::get_stoimost()
{
    return stoimost;
}
//модификаторы
void Tovar::set_naimenovanie(string N)
{
    naimenovanie = N;
}
void Tovar::set_kolichestvo(int K)
{
    kolichestvo = K;
}
void Tovar::set_stoimost(double S)
{
    stoimost = S;
}
//метод для просмотра атрибутов
void Tovar::show()
{
    cout << "naimenovanie :" << naimenovanie << endl;
    cout << "kolichestvo :" << kolichestvo << endl;
    cout << "stoimost :" << stoimost << endl;
}
```

**Lab2_main.cpp**

```
#include "Tovar.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
//функция для возврата объекта как результата
Tovar make_tovar()
{
    string s;
    int i;
    double d;
    cout << "Vvedite naimenovanie: ";
    cin >> s;
    cout << "Vvedite kolichestvo: ";
    cin >> i;
    cout << "Vvedite stoimost: ";
    cin >> d;
    Tovar t(s, i, d);
    return t;
}
//функция для передачи объекта как параметра
void print_tovar(Tovar t)
{
    t.show();
}
void main()
{
    //конструктор без параметров
    Tovar t1;
    t1.show();
    //коструктор с параметрами
    Tovar t2("Computer", 1, 15000);
    t2.show();
    //конструктор копирования
    Tovar t3 = t2;
    t3.set_naimenovanie("Telephon");
    t3.set_kolichestvo(2);
    t3.set_stoimost(5000.0);
    //конструктор копирования
    print_tovar(t3);
    //конструктор копирования
    t1 = make_tovar();
    t1.show();
}
```

Comment: зачем делать поля закрытыми, а потом обеспечивать доступ к ним и возможность их модификаций.   Вместо стольких мучений пишите структуру с такими полями

Comment: да это код с методички взятый для примера, проблема в том что он не хочет компилироваться и выдает 90 ошибок что довольно странно

Comment: **ИЗ** методички! "Я им говорю - не ложьте зеркало в парту! А они ложат."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не `void main()`, а `int main()`, и

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

должен идти первой строкой.

Других ошибок, препятствующих компиляции, не наблюдаю.

Что касается правильности самого кода в смысле того, что он должен делать то, что нужно - в этом смысле не смотрел.

Comment: В том самом компиляторе где файл "stdafx.h" должен идти первой строчкой функция main может быть void.